# Permission issues: can't write to directory owned by certain group

Tags: linux

I've created a user with uid 100999 and a group with gid 100999.

100999 is my user namespace. The goal is to write and manipulate files owned by my user namespace.

Added myself to group 100999.

```
uid=1000(me) gid=1000(me) groups=1000(me),10(wheel),983(libvirt),100999(test)
```

User 100999 belongs to group 100999 as well.

```
uid=100999(test) gid=100999(test) groups=100999(test)
```

Created a directory and changed it's ownership to 100999:100999. Also set permissions 775 to it.

```
drwxrwxr-x. 1 100999 100999    0 jul  9 10:29 test
drwxrwxr-x. 1 test test    0 jul  9 10:29 test
```

However, I can't do write operations inside directory "test" as user 1000 (myself), resulting in permission denied.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently one needs to restart the session after being added to a group.

Comment: Be very careful creating users and groups with numeric values greater than 64K.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! Didn't know about that.